# Benefit of Coproduct over `sealed trait`?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I read the following about [coproducts](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#coproducts-and-discriminated-unions) in the excellent [Shapeless Guide](http://underscore.io/books/shapeless-guide/):

> ... it’s worth stating that Coproducts aren’t particularly special. The functionality above can be achieved using Either and Nothing in place of :+:
>   and CNil.

Here's the above code:

```
import shapeless.{Coproduct, :+:, CNil, Inl, Inr}
case class Red()
case class Amber()
case class Green()
type Light = Red :+: Amber :+: Green :+: CNil

val red: Light = Inl(Red())
// red: Light = Inl(Red())
val green: Light = Inr(Inr(Inl(Green())))
// green: Light = Inr(Inr(Inl(Green())))
```

For my own understanding, what is the benefit, if any, of using a Coproduct over a `sealed trait`?

Comment: I use sealed trait when I want to hide the implementing case classes. e.g. put the implementing classes inside the companion object and make them private. No sense in cluttering up the type system.

Comment: Also, does Red extend Light? With sealed trait it would. Looks like you can use :+: if you want to avoid hierarchies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One benefit is similar to that of using type classes rather than inheritance: ad-hoc polymorphism. You can make a Coproduct out of any types, even those outside of your control, e.g. String and Int. You can't do that with a sealed trait (unless you made awkward `StringHolder` and `IntHolder` case classes to wrap them).

Answer (score 2):

Same as the benefit of using `HList` over a `case class`: you can write generic code which works for all coproducts, or all coproducts which satisfy some condition. And then use `Generic` to make the same code work with `sealed trait`s as well.

Comment: But, can't I get an `HList` for any case class using `Generic[A]` where `A` is the case class?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And applying `Generic[A]` to a sealed trait will give you a `Coproduct`.